# Equivalent class for transitive property

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, reasoner, hermit

I have an object property `partOf` which is transitive.

And I want to say that:

- `a partOf Year` then `a` is a `Term`
- `b partOf Term` then `b` is a `Course`

And simultaneously:

- `a partOf Knowledge_Group` then `a` is a `Knowledge_Area`
- `b partOf Knowledge_Area` then `b` is a `Course`

For that I'm using this to say `b partOf Term or Knowledge_Area` then `b` is a `Course`:

```
:Course rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :partOf ;
                              owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                                   owl:unionOf ( :Knowledge_Area
                                                                 :Term
                                                               )
                                                 ]
                            ] .
```

But when I run the reasoner I get all the courses listed as instances of the class `Term` and same for `Knowledge_Area`:

[image]

[image]

If I don't use the `or` and set that Course is equivalent only to `partOf some Term` or `partOf some Knowledge_Area` (separately and one at a time) I don't get this issue.

Is there a way I can say what I explained at the beginning and not get the courses inferred to be of type `Term`?

[Here there is a minimal example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a1fBG-nUaXoP_5SwBRiT6sAqPwou7-7M/view?usp=sharing):

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#partOf
:partOf rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                 owl:TransitiveProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Course
:Course rdf:type owl:Class ;
        owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                              owl:onProperty :partOf ;
                              owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                                   owl:unionOf ( :Knowledge_Area
                                                                 :Term
                                                               )
                                                 ]
                            ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Knowledge_Area
:Knowledge_Area rdf:type owl:Class ;
                owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                      owl:onProperty :partOf ;
                                      owl:someValuesFrom :Knowledge_Group
                                    ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Knowledge_Group
:Knowledge_Group rdf:type owl:Class ;
                 owl:disjointWith :Year .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Term
:Term rdf:type owl:Class ;
      owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :partOf ;
                            owl:someValuesFrom :Year
                          ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Year
:Year rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Course_1
:Course_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
          :partOf :Knowledge_Area_1 ,
                  :Term_1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Knowledge_Area_1
:Knowledge_Area_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
                  :partOf :Knowledge_Group_1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Knowledge_Group_1
:Knowledge_Group_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                            :Knowledge_Group .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Term_1
:Term_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :partOf :Year_1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/lucia/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-27#Year_1
:Year_1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 :Year .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse as suggested I created a minimal example and updated all the information accordingly

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I have added an answer with a possible solution to your problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of transitive roles are if `(x, y) \in R` and `(y, z) \in R` then `(x, z) \in R`. Based on this from your ontology you have that:

(1) `Course_1 partOf Knowledge_Area_1 partOf Knowledge_Group_1` which means `Course_1 partOf Knowledge_Group_1` which is equivalent to `Knowledge_Area`.

(2) `Course_1 partOf Term_1 partOf partOf Year_1`  which means `Course_1 partOf Year_1` which is equivalent to `Term`.

Hence `Course_1` is a `Term` and a `Knowledge_Area` and since `Course` is equivalent to `Term or Knowledge_Area`, `Course_1` is also a `Course`, which is pretty much what an explanation says for why `Course_1` is a `Term`.

In my opinion the key thing to realize here is that you in actual fact are dealing with different `partOf` relations, not a single one. The clue to this fact is that in different contexts you want to infer different type information from your `partOf` relation. Type information from relations in OWL is inferred mostly from domain and range restrictions. Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
ObjectProperty: partOf

ObjectProperty: partOfKA
    SubPropertyOf: partOf
    Domain: Course

ObjectProperty: partOfKG
    SubPropertyOf: partOf
    Domain: Knowledge_Area

ObjectProperty: partOfTerm
    SubPropertyOf: partOf
    Domain: Course

ObjectProperty: partOfYear
    SubPropertyOf: partOf
    Domain: Term

Class: Course
Class: Knowledge_Area


Class: Knowledge_Group
    DisjointWith: Year

Class: Term

Class: Year
    DisjointWith: Knowledge_Group

Individual: Course_1
    Facts:  
     partOfKA  Knowledge_Area_1,
     partOfTerm  Term_1

Individual: Knowledge_Area_1
    Facts:  partOfKG  Knowledge_Group_1

Individual: Knowledge_Group_1
    Types: Knowledge_Group


Individual: Term_1
    Facts: partOfYear  Year_1

Individual: Year_1
    Types: Year
```

Strictly speaking you do not need the `partOf` property in my example ontology. I merely added it for conceptual clarity. Moreover, in my example ontology there is no need for transitive properties.